# How can I parse an excel file within a zip file?

Tags: regex, excel, perl, parsing, zip

I want to be able to parse an excel within a zip file. I've been able to parse the zip file to return files within that compressed file, and if regex match brings up an excel file, I'd like to parse the file.

Here's the script that parses the zip file for the name of the excel spreadsheet...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $zipFile = Archive::Zip->new();
my $xl_file = "";
#open zipfile
$zipFile->read( '/home/user/Desktop/test.zip' ) == 0 || die "cannot read zip file\n";

#find all files within zipfile
my @files = $zipFile->memberNames('/home/user/Desktop/test.zip');
foreach my $file (sort @files) {
    #find all excel files
    if($file =~ m/(.*xls)/){
        $xl_file = $1;
            print "excel file found.\n";
    }
}
```

And this is the script that parses for the value in cells.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "/home/user/worksheet.xls";
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse("$filename");

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
open(FILE, '>', "parse.txt")||die "cannot open parse.txt!\n";

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
     my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
     my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();     
     my $s = $worksheet -> get_cell(2,2);
     my $p = $worksheet-> get_cell(2,3);
     print FILE $s->value()."\n";
     print FILE $p->value()."\n";
}
close FILE;
```

How do I integrate these together?

Comment: One way is to use pipes on the command line and print out file names from the first script only when you have extracted an excel file.  Then the second script takes that filename and parses it.  Something like `parseZip.pl myzip.zip | parseExcel.pl`.  The missing piece in your first script is to extract the actual file vs. just the file name.  The second script would need to be modified to accept file names on `STDIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of `Archive::Zip`, it's possible to get the contents of a compressed file member as a string:

```
$xls_content = $zipFile->contents($file);
```

And according to the documentation of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`, it's possible to parse a string containg the contents of an Excel file by passing the string as a reference:

```
my $workbook = $parser->parse(\$xls_content);
```

So you should be able to combine both together.

Another possibility is to extract the zip file member into a temporary file.